# It is possible to specify interfase to ssh command?

Tags: ubuntu, openssh

I have tried to connect by ssh to my remote server. But due to proxy restriction it is impossible because eth0 is used as default.

But I have wlan0 interface with my own internet gateway.

How I can specify to use wlan0 instead eth0 to my openssh client?

I tried the following, and it is does not work:

```
:~$ ssh -v 176.111.109.0
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/unmanner/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 176.111.109.0 [176.111.109.0] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 176.111.109.0 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 176.111.109.0 port 22: Connection refused
```

Also I tried "bind" option like this:

```
:~$ ssh -v -b 172.20.10.6 176.111.109.0
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/unmanner/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 176.111.109.0 [176.111.109.0] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 176.111.109.0 port 22: Connection timed out
ssh: connect to host 176.111.109.0 port 22: Connection timed out
```

Where "172.20.10.6" - IP address which is connected on the wlan0.

If I unplugged Ethernet cable - all works fine! But I would like have possibility for working with both interfaces.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you add a route to `176.111.109.0` through `wl0` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a route to your host say `176.111.109.0` through the gateway `w.x.y.z`

```
route add -host 176.111.109.0 gw w.x.y.z wlan0
```

This way all traffic to `176.111.109.0` goes through the specified `gateway IP address` on the specified `network interface` i.e. `wlan0`.

You can figure out the the gateway IP address for your wl0 from the output of `/sbin/route` when you have disconnected the wired network and have only wireless connected.

**NOTE**: The routes you added manually would be purged if you reboot the box. To make the routes persistent across reboots, you need to add the following line to your `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/route-wlan0`

```
# Host route for 176.111.109.0 through w.x.y.z on wlan0
176.111.109.0 via w.x.y.z dev wlan0
```

Comment: @Unmanner - note that the routes would be purged once you reboot the machine. I've updated the answer with info on how you can make the routes persist across reboots.

Comment: Thanks! But I actually need to reset this route after reboot, because I take my notebook from work to home sometimes :)